# Docker copies the files into the destination but deletes existing files

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have several files in a directory on the host machine which I am trying to copy to the Docker container.

The problem is that the files do get copied to the destination but all the existing files inside the destination directory get removed.

Before adding these new `ADD` lines to my Dockerfile, I had like 20 jar files in the lib directory, by adding these `ADD` lines the two crowd files below, all 20 existing jar files get deleted and the directory will now contains only two crowd files which were just copied from the host into the container!

This is my Dockerfile, I build it with `docker build . --no-cache -t mine/guacamole` and I have q a docker-compose file which creates the containers and starts them.

I tried without the `user ROOT` but it would not copy the `server.xml` and `tomcat.keystore`

```
FROM guacamole/guacamole

RUN sed -i 's/redirectPort="8443"/redirectPort="8443" server="" secure="true"/g' /usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml \
&& sed -i 's/<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">/<Server port="-1" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">/g' /usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml \
&& rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs/*  \
&& rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples/*  \
&& rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/*  \
&& rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager/*

WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat
USER root
COPY server.xml conf/server.xml
RUN chmod 660 conf/server.xml
USER root
ADD tomcat.keystore /usr/local/tomcat/
RUN chmod 644 tomcat.keystore
RUN chown root:staff /usr/local/tomcat/tomcat.keystore
ADD ./lib/crowd-auth-filter-1.0.0.jar /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/guacamole/WEB-INF/lib/crowd-auth-filter-1.0.0.jar
ADD ./lib/crowd-filter.properties /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/guacamole/WEB-INF/lib/crowd-filter.properties
RUN chmod 644 /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/guacamole/WEB-INF/lib/crowd-filter.properties
ADD web.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/guacamole/WEB-INF/web.xml
CMD /usr/local/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh && /usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: It'd be helpful to include the whole Dockerfile; ADD and COPY shouldn't work the way you're describing and so this fragment on its own wouldn't necessarily reproduce the problem.  It'd also be helpful to know how you're running the image to see that the files are missing.

Comment: Can you share your full dockerfile? and why you have specified the `USER root`?

Comment: @Kalanamith , it is too long to put here as a comment, I will post it as an answer to my own question - I hope you don't mind

Comment: Don't __answer__ to provide additional information, edit your question instead.

Comment: @tkausl 

All done, edited my question

Comment: @DavidMaze, I edited the question, can you please take a look and help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to copy `pg_hba.conf` to `/var/lib/postgresql/data/`, but made a typo.

```
# I did:
COPY ./pg_hba.conf /var/lib/postgres/data/ # lets call this data1

# While I should have done:
COPY ./pg_hba.conf /var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

I was scrathing my head why the `data1` contained `pg_hba.conf` only.
Obviously now, the `COPY` created directory `postgres` and `postgres/data`.
Maybe someone that will find this post has made