# Docker copy or add deletes existing files

Tags: docker

I have several files in a directory on the host machine which I am trying to copy to the Docker container.

The problem is that the files do get copied to the destination but all the existing files inside the destination directory get removed.

Before adding these new ADD lines to my Dockerfile, I had like 20 jar files in the lib directory, by adding these ADD lines the two crowd files below, all 20 existing jar files get deleted and the directory will now contains only two crowd files which were just copied from the host into the container!

I tried without the user ROOT but it would not copy the server.xml and tomcat.keystore

```
FROM guacamole/guacamole

RUN sed -i 's/redirectPort="8443"/redirectPort="8443" server="" secure="true"/g' /usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml \
&& sed -i 's/<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">/<Server port="-1" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">/g' /usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml \
&& rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs/*  \
&& rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples/*  \
&& rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/*  \
&& rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager/*

WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat
USER root
COPY server.xml conf/server.xml
RUN chmod 660 conf/server.xml
USER root
ADD tomcat.keystore /usr/local/tomcat/
RUN chmod 644 tomcat.keystore
RUN chown root:staff /usr/local/tomcat/tomcat.keystore
ADD ./lib/crowd-auth-filter-1.0.0.jar /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/guacamole/WEB-INF/lib/crowd-auth-filter-1.0.0.jar
ADD ./lib/crowd-filter.properties /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/guacamole/WEB-INF/lib/crowd-filter.properties
RUN chmod 644 /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/guacamole/WEB-INF/lib/crowd-filter.properties
ADD web.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/guacamole/WEB-INF/web.xml
CMD /usr/local/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh && /usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  guacd:
    hostname: guacd
    image: guacamole/guacd
    restart: always
    container_name: guacd
  mysql:
    hostname: mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: always
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE="guacamole"
      - MYSQL_USER="guacamole"
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD="password"
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="password"
  guacamole:
    build: .
    image: mine/guacamole
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8443:8443"
    links:
      - guacd
      - mysql
    container_name: guacamole
    environment:
      - GUACD_HOSTNAME=guacd
      - GUACAMOLE_HOME=/opt/guacamole-home

volumes:
  tmp-scripts:
```

To get things started:
1) I build the guacamole image with `docker build . --no-cache -t mine/guacamole`

2) Start the containers and create the services by running: `docker-compose up --force-recreate -d`

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker copies the files into the destination but deletes existing files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51975347/docker-copies-the-files-into-the-destination-but-deletes-existing-files)

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, it is the same question but with more detail, couldn't add everything there, the format is messed up there, and no one is able to see or answer that